# Fortran count intrinsic leading to segfault

Tags: arrays, count, fortran

I am experiencing some unexpected segfault after introducing a cleaner code making use of the `count` intrinsic. The code I had was

```
n = 0
do ico = 1,cpatch%ncohorts
   if (is_tropical(cpatch%pft(ico))) then
      n = n + 1
   end if
end do
```

where `cpatch%pft` is an array which by definition has length `cpatch%ncohorts`.

I substituted it with

```
n = count(is_tropical(cpatch%pft))
```

Also `is_tropical` is an logical array of size 17 defined as

```
   is_tropical(1:13)  = .false.
   is_tropical(14:17) = .true.
```

Is there a situation where these two portions of code would not perform the same set of operations?

Comment: I edited the question because `is_tropical` is not a function but an array.

Comment: Once you have some other bug around, *anything can happen*, that is the point of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior You must show the complete code to find the bug. We need a [mcve]. The usual suspect is a stack corruption die to array bounds overflow somewhere earlier.

Comment: Ok I get it. I guess what I am asking here is only if you expect these two portions of code to perform the same task given that everything else is equal.

Comment: It looks equivalent to me.